# How often are the scripts registered with RegisterStartupScript, RegisterScriptBlock etc. executed?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajax, updatepanel

Let's say I have a button which modifies some content inside an update panel:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label1.Text = "New Text";
}
```

I *also* want to execute some code on the client side, after the UpdatePanel has been updated. My first idea would be to execute `ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock` or `RegisterStartupScript`:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label1.Text = "New Text";

    var x = getSomeDatabaseQueryResultBasedOn(TextBox1.Text, ...);

    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(WebForm1), "SomeKey",
        "/* this is my script, using `x` */", true)
}
```

However, the [documentation of RegisterStartupScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338357.aspx) says:

> You use this method to register a startup script block that is included every time that an asynchronous postback occurs.

I don't want this code to execute *"every time that an asynchronous postback occurs"*. I want it to execute *only right now* (after control is back with the browser). If Button2 is clicked, I don't want any script executed, and if Button1 is clicked again, `x` might be different and I want a *new* script to be executed. Unfortunately, I didn't find a `ScriptManager.ExecuteOnce` method.

Is there such a method? Or did I just misunderstand the documentation of `RegisterStartupScript`?

Answer (score 0):

The very next line from that documentation says:

> "To register a script block for a control that is inside an
>   UpdatePanel control so that script is registered only when the
>   UpdatePanel control is updated, use the
>   RegisterClientScriptBlock(Control, Type, String, String, Boolean)
>   overload of this method."

Is that not what you want?

Comment: I'm not sure. I don't want the script block to be tied to a particular UpdatePanel control. I want the script block to be executed exactly once, namely when the current asyncronous postback returns.

Comment: I believe that is exactly what RegisterClientScriptBlock will do. But the easiest way to find out would be to try it for yourself and see.

Answer (score 0):

When you include the StartupScript duing the async postback, it will only exist in the *partial* response sent from the server.

If you do something like this:

```
if(ScriptManager.IsInAsyncPostBack)
{
  myDiv.InnerText = "partial response";
  ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), DateTime.Now.ToString("ssfff"), "alert(0);"), true);
}
```

Your response will look something like this:

```
|blabla|blabla|updatePanel_ctrl00|someparams
<div>partial response</div>
<script> alert(0); </script>
```

Thus that piece of javascript will execute as soon as the response is received.